# Is the output of a line integral over a scalar field a vector?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

In my physics book, the author writes that line integral of a scalar function $\phi$ over a curve $C$ can be written as the following:
$$\int_C\phi d{\textbf r}=\textbf{i}\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dx\,+\textbf{j}\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dy\,+\textbf{k}\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dz\,$$

It seemed to me that the output would be a value in $\mathbb R$ rather than in $\mathbb R^3$. 
Could you please explain?

He provided an example too, which I will add if you think it would help!

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/520091/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^3$, a scalar field
$$\phi:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R},\quad (x,y,z)\mapsto\phi(x,y,z)\ ,$$ or a vector field $${\bf F}:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}^3,\quad (x,y,z)\mapsto\bigl(u(x,y,z), v(x,y,z), w(x,y,z)\bigr)\ ,$$
and a curve
$$C:\quad t\mapsto{\bf r}(t)=\bigl(x(t),y(t),z(t)\bigr)\in\Omega\qquad(a\leq t\leq b)$$
in $\Omega$ there are various line integrals of these fields along $C$ possible, and the values of the integrals will be real numbers or vectors. The integral in your example is vector-valued, albeit I could not think of a concrete physical example where such an integral occurs.

We can integrate $\phi$ with respect to arc length on $C$:
$$\int_C\phi \>ds=\int_a^b \phi\bigl({\bf r}(t)\bigr)\>\bigl|\dot{\bf r}(t)\bigr|\>dt\quad\in{\mathbb R} ;$$
then in your way:
$$\int_C\phi\> d{\bf r}=\int_a^b \phi\bigl({\bf r}(t)\bigr)\>\dot{\bf r}(t)\>dt\quad\in{\mathbb R}^3\ .$$
Similarly we can with the vector field ${\bf F}$ form the line integrals
$$\int_C{\bf F}\> ds\in{\mathbb R}^3\>,\qquad\int_C{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}\in{\mathbb R},\quad \int_C{\bf F}\times d{\bf r}\in{\mathbb R}^3\>,$$
and maybe others, depending on the geometrical or physical purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, you have cleared up a lot for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The output is a vector in $ \mathbb R^3:$

$$\int_C\phi d{\textbf r}=(\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dx,\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dy,\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dz)$$

Comment: Is it not a numerical value? If we parametrize the curve $C=r(t)$ with $a\le t\le b$ then evaluate $\int_a^b\phi(r(t))\dot|v(t)|dt$ we get such a number, not a vector. $v(t)$ is the derivative of $r(t)$ wrt $t$

Comment: This really doesn't answer my question :(  if I am not seeing an obvious link please tell me what that is :)

Comment: @Kam the obvious link you are missing is right there in your comment. You set $d\mathbf{r} = |v(t)|dt$, but this is clearly nonsensical because one side is a vector but the other is a scalar.

Comment: @NinadMunshi So a more appropriate question would be what is the difference between a differential operator as a vector and one as a scalar? I have never seen the vector form used to evaluate integrals in math. Could you explain? Or should i post a different question altogether?

Comment: @Kam you have seen it before in the context of vector line integrals (or you will). In that case the vector differential was dotted with a vector field. This is not a differential operator.

Comment: If $r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ is a parametrisation of the curve$C$ (with $t \in [a,b]$) then $\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dx=\int_a^b \phi(r(t)) x'(t) dt \in \mathbb R$,  $\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dy=\int_a^b \phi(r(t)) y'(t) dt \in \mathbb R$ and  $\int_C\phi(x,y,z)dz=\int_a^b \phi(r(t)) z'(t) dt \in \mathbb R$, Hence $\int_C\phi d{\textbf r} \in \mathbb R^3.$